# Запрос к API Hive OS

Tags: php, hive

как выполнить запрос к API Hive OS ?

Желательно средствами PHP

Answer (score 1):

На сколько можно судить по документации (https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/HiveOS/public/2.1-beta) API Hive OS - это обычное HTTP API, даже что-то на подобии REST API (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST). Для работы по это API подойдет любой HTTP-клиент от cURL до Guzzle (http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/)

Comment: Спасибо )))))))

Comment: Если ответ удовлетворяет, то примите мой ответ как ответ на свой вопрос